# PsychToolbox SSVEP

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

I want to make an '`SSVEP`' flickering lines on the monitor using `PsychToolbox`.

By the way, when I made a 6Hz-flickering line, it sometimes disappeared: I guess there is some conflict between 6Hz-flickering stimulus presentation and the monitor refresh rate (60Hz).

How can I solve this problem?
If you could provide the code, it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you should wait for "vsync" (just before displaying a new 60-Hz frame), and then "flip" to the other (already filled) screen buffer.